# Calling one function from another and pass parameter angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, function

## editContact.html

```
 <h1>Select record to edit </h1>{{msg}}{{phone_number}}</br></br>
<form>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>First Name: </td><td><input type="text" ng-model="firstname">
 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Second Name: </td><td><input type="text" ng-model="secondname">
 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Email: </td><td><input type="email" ng-model="email"></td>
    </tr>       
    <tr>
        <td>Status: </td>
        <td><input type="radio"  value="active" ng-model = 
   "status">Active</td>
        <td><input type="radio"  value="inactive" ng-
   model="status">Inactive</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="button" value="Submit" ng-click="updateData()" />
    </tr>   {{error}}
    </form>
   <div ng-init="displayContacts()">
   <table border="1px">
  <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Second Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Phone Number</th>
        <th>Status</th>
    </tr>   
   </thead> 
   <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="contact in data">
            <td>{{contact.first_name}}</td>
            <td>{{contact.second_name}}</td>
            <td>{{contact.email}}</td>
            <td>{{contact.phone_number}}</td>
            <td>{{contact.status}}</td>
            <td><button ng-
     click="editContacts(contact.phone_number);">Edit</button></td>
     </tr>
     </tbody>
     </table>
```

## app.js

```
app.controller('EditController', function($scope, $http, ) {
        
    $scope.message = 'Hello from EditController';
    $scope.updateContacts = function(){
      $http.post("update.php", {
        'first_name':$scope.firstname, 
        'second_name' : $scope.secondname, 
        'email' : $scope.email,
        
        'status' : $scope.status}).success(function(msg){
        $scope.msg = "Data updated";
        }).error(function(error){
        $scope.error(error);
        })
      }

      $scope.displayContacts = function(){
         
          $http.get("retrieveAll.php").
          success(function(data){
              $scope.data = data;
          })
      }         
        $scope.editContacts = function(phone_number){
            $scope.phone_number = phone_number
            //var phone= phone_number;  
            $scope.msg = "Edit for number :";

    }
```

The parameter phone_number is being passed from editContact.html with the function editContact(contact.phone_number). I want to send this now to the function updateContact where I use phone_number to make a php call to update contact with that particular phone_number.

I looked at service but dont know how I can apply for this situation, would appreciate if someone can show me the code or can suggest

Comment: What's not working? You're setting phone_number on the $scope, which means it will be available in `updateContacts`

Comment: where your input phone number of you ?

Comment: Hey, its working, I didnt realize the $scope is global. So correct me if I am wrong, if in any controller you declare a variable with $scope.xx = "xx";

Comment: @code_ethusiast actually $scope is not global. it's available to itself and any child scopes

Comment: if you want it to be global, use $rootScope

Comment: @tcrite ok, thank you for the help guys!!!